# How to save matplotlib plot with a custom filename that includes timestamp?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to write a program in Python which can save a plot with a filename that includes the timestamp as part of its name with `matplotlib`, for example, "temperature_vs_time_16-09-23" (16-09-23 meaning 4:09:23PM). I tried using an fstring and `time.strftime('format', time.time())` but it doesn't seem to be working. Does anyone have an easy work around for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `datetime` and join strings as filename

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
values = np.random.randint(0,10,100)
now = datetime.now()
today_filename = "temperature_vs_time_"+now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")+".png"
plt.plot(values)
plt.savefig(today_filename)
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked really well for me and was simple to follow :D

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way by using pandas to get current datetime, it should work

```
date = pd.to_datetime('now').strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

### Filename of your choice
filename = 'temp_{name}'.format(name=date)

### Visualize
plt.plot(df['column'].value_counts())

### Save figure
plt.savefig(filename+'.jpg', dpi=100)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked as well, but I decided to use the other method suggested, but thanks though! :D

Comment: No Prob , Glad it worked for you.